# How to group by two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please consider below. I wish to list the number of times that each users made reservations for a conference room, and how many different rooms he/she used:

```
room  user
----------
1     1    
2     1
3     2
4     3
4     3
```

Desired output:

```
user  reservations   rooms
-------------------------
1     2              2
2     1              1
3     2              1
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I now have:

```
select [user], count(1)
from   [table]
group by [user]
```

But this doesn't give me the rooms count. Adding another `count()` doesn't work.

Comment: Without posting actual Schema we can't actually help - Is the table rooms or Reservations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a `count ( distinct <column> )` for the room

```
select [user], count(*) as reservations, count(distinct room) as rooms
from   [table]
group by [user]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation    with distinct for room

```
  Select  user,  count(*) reservation_ numbr,count(distinct room) as rooms
  from t group by user
```